# Selecting the file with latest timestamp using MORE command

Tags: unix

I have three files.

```
log.20150622
log.20150623
log.20150624
```

I want to open the file which has the latest timestamp in a script. In the above set of files, the file with the latest timestamp is log.20150624  .

When i use the command `more log.*` ,  log.20150622 gets opened.

Could you help me on this issue ?

Comment: `more log.20150624`... `more` doesn't care about the contents of the files, nor their timestamps, and thus won't make a decision about what to display based on either criterion - it just displays the files you tell it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tail` to limit the result of the wildcard to the last one. Try it:

```
ls -1 log.* | tail -n 1
```

Then you can pass it to `more`, either via a sub-command:

```
more $(ls -1 log.* | tail -n 1)
```

or via xargs:

```
ls -1 log.* | tail -n 1 | xargs more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  find /foldername | sort -n | tail -1
```